ASUS VS230H-P monitor shows as "unknown monitor" on Framework 13 on Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 on my framework 13 (Intel Core ultra series 1). I have 2 additional monitors connected to a USB 3 dock. One monitor, my HP monitor works great and is detected in display settings just fine. The other is an ASUS VS230H-P monitor and is stuck at 1024x768
xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-5 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DP-6 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  

The laptop is closed, so the display should be disabled. I've checked and DisplayLink shouldn't be required.

